# How can i change the placeholder text color to white

Tags: html, css, placeholder, textcolor, search-box

I am trying to figure out how to change the color of placeholder text for a search box to white, here is my css:

[image]

Heres the html:

[image]

Answer (score 6):

You can use the `::placeholder` pseudo class.

```css
input {
  background-color: #907;
}

input::placeholder {
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" placeholder="Enter Description Here" />
```

However, it is not standardized, and may not work well across all browsers.

Add vendor prefixes for better support:

```css
input {
  background-color: #907;
}

input::placeholder {
  color: #fff;
}

::-webkit-input-placeholder {  /* Chrome/Opera/Safari */
  color: #fff;
}
::-moz-placeholder {  /* Firefox 19+ */
  color: #fff;
}
:-moz-placeholder { /* Firefox 18- */
  color: #fff;
}
:-ms-input-placeholder {  /* Edge/IE 10+ */
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" placeholder="Desciption" />
```

**Important:**  Do not group these selectors, as explained in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44913155/using-multiple-vendor-specific-css-selectors-at-once/45045464).